Typescript generics in function instead of class
So, I'm trying to implement a way to get data from different data sources, each pointing to, say, a search service.
I've created the following class:
export class GoogleSearchResult {
    constructor() {}
    data: string;
}

I've also created an abstract class that would handle any search provider:
export abstract class ISearchResult<T> {
    result: T;
}

export class SearchResult<T> implements ISearchResult<T> {
    constructor(result: T) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    result: T;
}

here, T could be anything, but my idea would be to use it to set a GoogleSearchResult, BingSearchResult, etc.
To query the data, I have:
export abstract class ISearchDataSource {
    abstract getData<T>(query: string): Promise<ISearchResult<T>>;
}

To implement the ISearchDataSource abstract class, I've done:
@Injectable()
export class GoogleDataSource implements ISearchDataSource {
    constructor() {}

    async getData<GoogleSearchResult>(): Promise<ISearchResult<GoogleSearchResult>> {
        const data: GoogleSearchResult = new GoogleSearchResult();
        return new SearchResult<GoogleSearchResult>(data);
    }
}

But it doesn't work! The error I see is:
Type 'import("/Users/user/Projects/project1/src/models/google-search-result").GoogleSearchResult' is not assignable to type 'GoogleSearchResult'.
  'GoogleSearchResult' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'import("/Users/user/Projects/project1/src/models/google-search-result").GoogleSearchResult'

If I use generics on the ISearchDataSource class instead of the getData method, it works. The problem here is that I want to have these data sources with different functions and returns. Like this:
@Injectable()
export class GoogleDataSource2 implements ISearchDataSource2<GoogleSearchResult> {
    constructor() {}

    async getData(): Promise<ISearchResult<GoogleSearchResult>> {
        const data: GoogleSearchResult = new GoogleSearchResult();
        return new SearchResult<GoogleSearchResult>(data);
    }
}

export abstract class ISearchDataSource2<T> {
    abstract getData(): Promise<ISearchResult<T>>;
}


• There's no point in using abstract classes and then implements-ing it in another class. Either write abstract class X {} class Y extends X {} or interface X {} class Y implements X {}. This is likely a distraction from your question, so please [edit] to remove it. • "The problem here is that I want to have these data sources with different functions and returns." What does this mean? Your ISerarchDataSource2<T> is the correct way of writing what you're writing. You seem to have found that on your own; can you demonstrate a problem with it? Right now this isn't a [mre].
